# SVG Path drawing

Tags: javascript, svg

What I try is to draw using Path in SVG javascript. This code below works for Polylines in SVG javascript and I want to use the same code for Path in SVG.

Error I get is:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
> at SVG.PathArray.parse (svg.js:889)
>at SVG.PathArray.SVG.Array (svg.js:433)
>at new SVG.PathArray (svg.js:686)
>at initializer.plot (svg.js:4413)
>at create.path (svg.js:4454)
>at create_New_Path (javascript_mainSVG.js:203)
>at HTMLDivElement.pointerDown (javascript_mainSVG.js:97)
```

The libraries I use are from svgjs.dev.

This is three functions for trigger events pointerdown, pointermove, pointerup

```
create_New_Path(event.pageX,event.pageY);
add_To_Current_Path(event.pageX,event.pageY);
end_Current_Path(event.pageX,event.pageY);
```

Creating a new path (x,y) "pointerdown"

```
function create_New_Path(x,y) {
    myPath= SVG.path([[x,y]]);
    myPath.fill('none').stroke({color: `${selectedColor}`, width: 2, linecap: "round"});
}
```

Adding to current Path "pointermove"

```
function add_To_Current_Path(x,y) {
    arr = myPath.plot();
    arr.value.push([x,y]);
    myPath.plot(arr);
}
```

Ending the current path "pointerup"

```
function end_Current_Path(x,y) {
    arr = myPath.plot();
    arr.value.push([x,y]);
    myPath.plot(arr);
    myPath = null;
}
```

Is it possible to use the same code as for Polyline. Feels like it should work by replacing path instead of polyline.

Comment: > `event.pageX, ev.pageY` Seems like it should be either `event` OR `ev`

Comment: No that will not work @ChrisG

Comment: There is some error like this when calling "push" function: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: So, is it possible that either `event.pageX` or `ev.pageY` is `undefined`...? Because it almost has to be that way. This will probably cause other issues down the line. Can you add your actual event handler code to the question?

Comment: Okay sorry @ChrisG I meant that I know about events and also that it always should be that way, I just wrote it wrong in my code above. Im using always the same event name as you said. It works for polyline but not for path.